# Python, SQLAlchemy: Query, filter and return value

Tags: python, database-design, sqlalchemy, pylons

Say I run a query with a filter,

```
Session.query(model.Place).join(model.Location).filter(model.Location.great_circle_distance(location) < r)
```

In order to get the results of this query, it had to have calculated `model.Location.great_circle_distance(location)`. After running this query, I can get a list of `Places` which match that criteron of having a `great_circle_distance` less than `r`, but, is there any way to return both the result of that calculation and the list of Places that match that query in one fell swoop?

Comment: is `great_circle_distance(location)` a method you have added to the Location model? is `location` and `r` a local variable defined just before this query line?

Comment: Is there a reason you cant do the great_circle_distance() call on one line, and the query on the next with the result of that call? It seems unnecessary to try and formulate a query command that would aggregate that value into the result.

Comment: Actually your comment was real helpful... I think I've found a solution to my problem thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `join`, `column_property` and `mapper` to derive a class that is, essentially, a database view.  But unless you intended to use that in more than one place, or the number of rows is huge, I would just do a separate query to get the `Location` objects and use `map` to compute the circle distances.

Comment: What do you mean use `map` to compute circle distances? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: If you used two separate queries, then you would query `model.Location` joined to `model.Place` and retrieve all objects.  Then you would `map` those objects onto your distance calculation to get all the distances.